# Tool for type constraints for REST in AWS lambda (Or JS in general)

Tags: javascript

I want to create a rest API in aws lambda with javascript, but I have a problem. Unlike Django Rest, there is no prepackaged rest interface that allows setting the exact types and constraints of pushable json objects.
So lets say I want to have an order endpoint where the orders have the following constraints:

```
{
    product:[valid productID as string],
    amount: [number of items from 1 to 1000],
    customer: [will be automatically filled in by the system, isn't part of the post request],
    comment: [string with 0 to 1000 characters, or null],
    status: ["awaiting payment","processing","sent out","finished", will also be filled out by the system and isn't part of the post request],
    id:[automatic]
}
```

So how can I set item constraints like these in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished by validating the payload against [JSON Schema](https://json-schema.org/). A library to do this in JavaScript is [AJV](https://ajv.js.org/).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).